# Dropbox Java Spring Boot connector

Tags: java, spring, junit

I've created a service that connects to Dropbox and makes it possible to download and upload files, create and list folders and remove file or folder.

Full code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/MajewskiKrzysztof/spring-boot-dropbox

**DropboxConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
class DropboxConfiguration {

    @Value("${dropbox.accessToken}")
    private String accessToken;

    @Bean
    public DbxClientV2 dropboxClient() {
        DbxRequestConfig config = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("example-app").build();
        return new DbxClientV2(config, accessToken);
    }

}
```

**DropboxServiceImpl**

```
@Service
class DropboxServiceImpl implements DropboxService {

    private final DbxClientV2 client;

    public DropboxServiceImpl(DbxClientV2 client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream downloadFile(String filePath) throws DropboxException {
        return handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().download(filePath).getInputStream(),
                String.format("Error downloading file: %s", filePath));
    }

    @Override
    public FileMetadata uploadFile(String filePath, InputStream fileStream) throws DropboxException {
        return handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().uploadBuilder(filePath).uploadAndFinish(fileStream),
                String.format("Error uploading file: %s", filePath));
    }

    @Override
    public CreateFolderResult createFolder(String folderPath) {
        return handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().createFolderV2(folderPath), "Error creating folder");
    }

    @Override
    public FolderMetadata getFolderDetails(String folderPath) throws DropboxException {
        return getMetadata(folderPath, FolderMetadata.class, String.format("Error getting folder details: %s", folderPath));
    }

    @Override
    public FileMetadata getFileDetails(String filePath) throws DropboxException {
        return getMetadata(filePath, FileMetadata.class, String.format("Error getting file details: %s", filePath));
    }

    @Override
    public ListFolderResult listFolder(String folderPath, Boolean recursiveListing, Long limit) throws DropboxException {
        ListFolderBuilder listFolderBuilder = client.files().listFolderBuilder(folderPath);
        if (Objects.nonNull(recursiveListing)) {
            listFolderBuilder.withRecursive(recursiveListing);
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(limit)) {
            listFolderBuilder.withLimit(limit);
        }

        return handleDropboxAction(listFolderBuilder::start, String.format("Error listing folder: %s", folderPath));
    }

    @Override
    public ListFolderResult listFolderContinue(String cursor) throws DropboxException {
        return handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().listFolderContinue(cursor), "Error listing folder");
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFile(String filePath) {
        handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().deleteV2(filePath), String.format("Error deleting file: %s", filePath));
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFolder(String folderPath) {
        handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().deleteV2(folderPath), String.format("Error deleting folder: %s", folderPath));
    }

    private <T> T handleDropboxAction(DropboxActionResolver<T> action, String exceptionMessage) {
        try {
            return action.perform();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String messageWithCause = String.format("%s with cause: %s", exceptionMessage, e.getMessage());
            throw new DropboxException(messageWithCause, e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T getMetadata(String path, Class<T> type, String message) {
        Metadata metadata = handleDropboxAction(() -> client.files().getMetadata(path),
                String.format("Error accessing details of: %s", path));

        checkIfMetadataIsInstanceOfGivenType(metadata, type, message);
        return (T) metadata;
    }

    private <T> void checkIfMetadataIsInstanceOfGivenType(Metadata metadata, Class<T> validType, String exceptionMessage) {
        boolean isValidType = validType.isInstance(metadata);
        if (!isValidType) {
            throw new DropboxException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**DropboxIntTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootSharepointRestApplication.class)
public class DropboxIntTest {

    private static final String TEST_FOLDER_PATH = "/Test Folder";
    private static final String TEST_FILE_PATH = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "testFile.txt");
    private static final Integer TEST_FILE_SIZE = 17;

    @Autowired
    private DropboxService dropboxService;

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exceptions = ExpectedException.none();

    @Rule
    public final TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Before
    public void createTestFolder() throws Exception {
        dropboxService.createFolder(TEST_FOLDER_PATH);

        File tempUploadFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("testFile.txt");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempUploadFile, "test file content", "UTF-8");
        String testFilePath = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "testFile.txt");
        dropboxService.uploadFile(testFilePath, new FileInputStream(tempUploadFile));
    }

    @After
    public void deleteTestFolder() {
        dropboxService.deleteFolder(TEST_FOLDER_PATH);
    }

    @Test
    public void downloadFile_shouldReturnNotEmptyInputStream() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = dropboxService.downloadFile(TEST_FILE_PATH);
        assertThat(inputStream.available()).isEqualTo(TEST_FILE_SIZE);
    }

    @Test
    public void downloadFile_shouldThrowExceptionIfFileNotExists() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.downloadFile("not-existing-file");
    }

    @Test
    public void uploadFile_shouldReturnUploadedFileDetails() throws Exception {
        File tempUploadFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("teamLogo.png");
        String filePath = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, tempUploadFile.getName());
        FileMetadata fileMetadata = dropboxService.uploadFile(filePath, new FileInputStream(tempUploadFile));
        assertThat(fileMetadata.getId()).isNotBlank();
    }

    @Test
    public void uploadFile_shouldCreateFolderIfNotExists() throws Exception {
        File tempUploadFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("teamLogo.png");
        String filePath = String.format("%s/%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "not existing folder", tempUploadFile.getName());
        dropboxService.uploadFile(filePath, new FileInputStream(tempUploadFile));

        FolderMetadata folderDetails = dropboxService
                .getFolderDetails(String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "not existing folder"));
        assertThat(folderDetails.getId()).isNotBlank();
    }

    @Test
    public void createFolder_shouldCreateFolder() {
        String folderPath = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "new folder");
        CreateFolderResult folder = dropboxService.createFolder(folderPath);

        FolderMetadata folderDetails = dropboxService.getFolderDetails(folderPath);
        assertThat(folderDetails.getId()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(folderDetails.getId()).isEqualToIgnoringCase(folder.getMetadata().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void createFolder_shouldThrowExceptionIfFolderAlreadyExists() {
        String folderPath = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "new folder");

        dropboxService.createFolder(folderPath);

        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.createFolder(folderPath);
    }

    @Test
    public void getFolderDetails_shouldReturnFolderDetails() {
        FolderMetadata folderDetails = dropboxService.getFolderDetails(TEST_FOLDER_PATH);

        assertThat(folderDetails.getId()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(folderDetails.getName()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(folderDetails.getPathDisplay()).isNotBlank();
    }

    @Test
    public void getFolderDetails_shouldThrowExceptionIfFolderNotExists() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.getFolderDetails("/not existing folder");
    }

    @Test
    public void getFileDetails_shouldReturnFileDetails() {
        FileMetadata fileDetails = dropboxService.getFileDetails(TEST_FILE_PATH);

        assertThat(fileDetails.getId()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(fileDetails.getPathDisplay()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(fileDetails.getName()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(fileDetails.getSize()).isEqualTo(TEST_FILE_SIZE.longValue());
        assertThat(fileDetails.getServerModified()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(fileDetails.getServerModified()).isBefore(new Date());
    }

    @Test
    public void getFileDetails_shouldThrowExceptionIfFileNotExists() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.getFileDetails("/not-existing-file.pdf");
    }

    @Test
    public void listFolder_shouldReturnFolderItems() throws Exception {
        File tempUploadFile1 = temporaryFolder.newFile("testFile2.txt");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempUploadFile1, "test file content", "UTF-8");
        String testFilePath1 = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "testFile2.txt");
        dropboxService.uploadFile(testFilePath1, new FileInputStream(tempUploadFile1));

        File tempUploadFile2 = temporaryFolder.newFile("testFile3.txt");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempUploadFile2, "test file content", "UTF-8");
        String testFilePath2 = String.format("%s/%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "inner folder", "testFile3.txt");
        dropboxService.uploadFile(testFilePath2, new FileInputStream(tempUploadFile2));

        ListFolderResult listFolderResult = dropboxService.listFolder(TEST_FOLDER_PATH, true, 10L);
        assertThat(listFolderResult.getEntries()).hasSize(5);

        List<FileMetadata> files = listFolderResult.getEntries().stream()
                .filter(entity -> entity instanceof FileMetadata)
                .map(entity -> (FileMetadata) entity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        assertThat(files).hasSize(3);

        List<FolderMetadata> folders = listFolderResult.getEntries().stream()
                .filter(entity -> entity instanceof FolderMetadata)
                .map(entity -> (FolderMetadata) entity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        assertThat(folders).hasSize(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void listFolder_shouldTrowExceptionIfFolderNotExists() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.listFolder("/not existing folder", true, 10L);
    }

    @Test
    public void listFolderContinue_shouldListNextPathOfItems() throws Exception {
        File tempUploadFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("testFile2.txt");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempUploadFile, "test file content", "UTF-8");
        String testFilePath1 = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "testFile2.txt");
        dropboxService.uploadFile(testFilePath1, new FileInputStream(tempUploadFile));

        ListFolderResult listFolderResult = dropboxService.listFolder(TEST_FOLDER_PATH, false, 1L);
        assertThat(listFolderResult.getEntries()).hasSize(1);

        String cursor = listFolderResult.getCursor();
        listFolderResult = dropboxService.listFolderContinue(cursor);
        assertThat(listFolderResult.getEntries()).hasSize(1);

        cursor = listFolderResult.getCursor();
        listFolderResult = dropboxService.listFolderContinue(cursor);
        assertThat(listFolderResult.getEntries()).hasSize(0);
    }

    @Test
    public void listFolderContinue_shouldThrowExceptionIfWrongCursorProvided() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.listFolderContinue(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteFile_shouldDeleteFile() {
        FileMetadata fileDetails = dropboxService.getFileDetails(TEST_FILE_PATH);
        assertThat(fileDetails.getId()).isNotBlank();

        dropboxService.deleteFile(TEST_FILE_PATH);

        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.getFileDetails(TEST_FILE_PATH);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteFile_shouldThrowExceptionIfFileNotExists() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.deleteFolder("/not-existing-file");
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteFolder_shouldDeleteFolder() {
        String testFolder = String.format("%s/%s", TEST_FOLDER_PATH, "test folder");
        dropboxService.createFolder(testFolder);

        FolderMetadata folderDetails = dropboxService.getFolderDetails(testFolder);
        assertThat(folderDetails.getId()).isNotBlank();

        dropboxService.deleteFolder(testFolder);

        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.getFolderDetails(testFolder);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteFolder_shouldThrowExceptionIfFolderNotExists() {
        exceptions.expect(DropboxException.class);
        dropboxService.deleteFolder("/not-existing-folder");
    }

}
```

**DropboxException**

```
public class DropboxException extends RuntimeException {

    public DropboxException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public DropboxException(String message, Exception cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

**DropboxActionResolver**

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DropboxActionResolver<T> {

    T perform() throws Exception;

}
```

What do you think of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part it looks fine. There are a few parts that may be changed. For example, I think that the handle `handleDropboxAction` method and the usage of the `DropboxActionResolver` functional interface might be a bit of an overkill.

You could achieve the exact same behavior without creating a custom interface to essentially wrap it an try-catch clause.

`listFolder` arguments could be made primitive (to avoid the null checks).

Your various `throws DropboxException` declaration could be omitted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your review. I will apply some of your suggestions. I used 'DropboxActionResolver' because some of Dropbox API methods throw checked exceptions and this can't be used with standard functional interfaces

Comment: That make sense, but you can always create a wrapper exception object that will extend `RuntimeException` to propagate an exception outside of a lambda body.